# Google Chrome permission settings for JavaScript difference between Allow and Allow(default)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, permissions, settings

The question seems silly but when I have selected `Allow(default)` for JavaScript, the website content was not displaying. Now I changed it to `Allow`, and all the content displayed!

So, curious to know if there is a difference in between these options regarding backend logic and the way they works.

Edit: I am using Google Chrome `Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)` in `MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.2 (19C57)`.

Here I have attached screenshot for the reference.

[image: 1]

Comment: seems like a bug.